# How to create download link in jQuery

Tags: jquery

By using below jQuery I am getting proper url link but I have to make it downloadable link or open it on other tab. Currently by clicking on url it's opening on the same page.

```
 var filename=ui.item.brouchersFile;
 var id=ui.item.brouchersId;
 <a href="../../download/product_brochures/${id}/${filename}">${filename}</a>;
```

Comment: <a href="url" target="_blank">file name</a>

Comment: If you want the file to be a direct download, you have to send the proper headers from your server side

Answer (score 0):

To Open link in a New Window or Tab, just add a **target="_blank"** attribute to your links (anchor tags).

```
<a href="../../download/product_brochures/${id}/${filename}" target="_blank">${filename}</a>;
```

Refer this - [How to Make Links Open in a New Window or Tab](https://www.thesitewizard.com/html-tutorial/open-links-in-new-window-or-tab.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```
var filename=ui.item.brouchersFile;
var id=ui.item.brouchersId;
<a href="../../download/product_brochures/${id}/${filename}" target="_blank">${filename}</a>;
```

`target="_blank"` will help you to open the URL in new tab.